# I need to write a simple program that goes through a folder with subfolders and deletes the last file in each subfolder beneath the folder

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sh

I searched through the site and found nothing like what I needed, so I decided to make my own question.

I am using linux, trying to figure out a way to do what I described using tools like find, awk, rm, and others; but so far I have not been able to think of a way.

A bit of background,

- The files are renamed in a neat alphabetical manner. No white space.
- Subfolders are named like that too.
- When I say last file, I mean the last file by alphabetical sorting.
- The amount of files in each subfolder is not same. Some subfolders have 56 files, while others don't even hit two digit. So I can't execute a convenient command like this:

`rm ./folder-*/020.jpg`

Which I would have been able to if all subfolders had the same amount of files in them.

To illustrate the directory, it would be like

```
./original-folder
./original-folder/subfolder-001/001.jpg
./original-folder/subfolder-001/002.jpg
./original-folder/subfolder-001/003.jpg
./original-folder/subfolder-002/001.jpg
./original-folder/subfolder-002/002.jpg
./original-folder/subfolder-003/001.jpg
```

And so on.
I want it to look like this basically

```
./original-folder
./original-folder/subfolder-001/001.jpg
./original-folder/subfolder-001/002.jpg
./original-folder/subfolder-002/001.jpg
./original-folder/subfolder-003/001.jpg
```

Note that last file is one less than before.

My solution was to find a way to start a list every time the program went to a new folder, and then borrowing the last item of that list for rm command but I have absolutely 0 idea on how to do that within bash or anything.

Feels like I need a fully functional programming language to do that.

Comment: Last file in alphabetical order yes. I generally sort them with  sort -d.

Comment: use os.walk, sort the resulting filenames and then use filelist[-1] to get the name, then you can use os.remove(filelist[-1]) to remove the file.

Comment: Given the last line in your example, is it true that if there's only 1 file in a directory you do NOT want to delete it despite it being the last file in alphabetical order?

Comment: Yes. That is what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your input files are named in a sortable way and don't contain any spaces as shownin the example in your question:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

find ./original-folder -type f |
sort |
awk '
    {
        dir = $0
        sub("/[^/]+$","",dir)
    }
    dir != prev {
        prt()
        numFiles = 0
        prev = dir
    }
    { files[++numFiles] = $0 }
    END { prt() }

    function prt(       fileNr, endNr) {
        endNr = numFiles - ( numFiles == 1 ? 0 : 1 )
        for ( fileNr=1; fileNr <= endNr; fileNr++ ) {
            print files[fileNr]
        }
    }
' |
xargs -I {} echo rm -- '{}'
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
rm -- ./original-folder/subfolder-001/001.jpg
rm -- ./original-folder/subfolder-001/002.jpg
rm -- ./original-folder/subfolder-002/001.jpg
rm -- ./original-folder/subfolder-003/001.jpg
```

Remove the `echo` once you've initially tested and are happy with the result. The `sort` may not be necessary depending on whatever order `find` outputs it's results but it won't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can create files on the directory this method worked for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
originalFolder=/path/to/your/directory/containing/orignal-folder

ls $originalFolder > folder_list.txt

while read -r line; do
  ls -r "$originalFolder/$line" > file_list.txt
  fileLength=$(wc -l < file_list.txt)
  if [ "$fileLength" -gt 1 ]
  then
      rmFile=$(head -n 1 file_list.txt)
      rm "$originalFolder/$line/$rmFile"
  fi
done < folder_list.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about this site before. Edited the issues accordingly.